# Integer vs floating point numbers in IEEE single format

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754, ieee

Can any integer number between the smallest and largest positive normal floating-point numbers in [IEEE single format](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/single-precision-format) be stored exactly in this floating-point system?
If yes, please explain, possibly providing an example.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested.

Answer (score 3):

No.

In IEEE-754 binary32, a finite number is represented in the format ± *x*.*xxx*…*xxx*<sub>2</sub> • 2<sup>*e*</sup>, where each *x* is a bit, there are 23 bits after the “.”, and −126 ≤ *e* ≤ 127. It is in normal form if the first *x* is 1. So the largest positive normal number representable is + 1.111…111<sub>2</sub> • 2<sup>127</sup> = (2 − 2<sup>−23</sup>) • 2<sup>127</sup> = 2<sup>128</sup> − 2<sup>104</sup>.

The smallest positive normal number is + 1.000…000<sub>2</sub> • 2<sup>−126</sup> = 2<sup>−126</sup>. Between these lies the integer 2<sup>24</sup>+1 = 16,777,217. This integer is not representable because, in binary, it is 1000…0001<sub>2</sub>, where there are 23 zero bits between the ones, making 25 bits in total, so it cannot be represented in the form ± *x*.*xxx*…*xxx*<sub>2</sub> • 2<sup>*e*</sup>, which has just 24 bits in the significand.